# At what speed does the time run in Vaikunth and Goloka?

Tags: vaikuntha, goloka

At what speed does the time run in Vaikunth , the abode of Vishnu ?

And what about Go-Loka , the abode of Krishna , at what speed does the time run over there ?

(with respect to earth)

Answer (score 1):

There are two zones in COSMOS / **vishav** (which has multiple universe/ **Jagat**; which in turn has many superclusters/**brahmaand**; within which are many galaxies/ **dweep**; which in turn has many stars each with planetary and satellite moons system like our solar system/ **sansaar** ); 1) dependent on **word; space; atom; time** and 2) beyond Gunas as well as time **(Guna-teet and KAALA-TEET)**.                            The following are KAALA-TEET                                                        **1) **Vaikunth 2) Golok 3) badri ka ashram 3) Swet-dweep 4) Ksheer sagar 5) Siddha Shila****